# Prove that if 2 divides n and 7 divides n, then 14 divides n

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Okay so I have to prove this. I can write that if 2 divides n and 7 divides n, then there must be integers k and m such that
$2*k=n$
and
$7*m=n$

So $14*k*m=n^2$

But what to do after that?

If I say that then 14 divides $n^2$, I get bit of a circular argument, but if I write that n divides $14*k*m$, then I don't know what to do next.

Any help/suggestions?

Comment: Some general advice: when you are asked to *prove* something that seems so incredibly obvious that it appears all proofs would go in circles, what you're really being asked to do is to **use the explicitly allowed axioms and definitions** to prove it.  [Don't start doubting your intuition about the patently obvious.](https://www.maa.org/external_archive/devlin/LockhartsLament.pdf)  Just examine the given definitions to establish to your satisfaction that they are sufficient, *all by themselves,* to formally prove the statement in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following from what you have written, $$n = 2k=7m \implies k=\frac{7m}{2}.$$
Since $k$ is an integer and $\gcd(2,7)=1$, $m/2$ must be an integer; i.e., $m/2=r \implies m=2r$, where $r$ is an integer. Therefore,
$$n=7m=7\times 2r = 14 r.$$
Q.E.D.

Answer (score 2):

You can say much more: **Say $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime. If $a|n$ and $b|n$ then $ab|n$.**

Proof: Since $a|n$ we can write $n=ak$. Now since $b|ak$ we have, by Euclid lemma $b|k$, so $k=bl$. Thus $n=abl$ and so $ab|n$.

Answer (score 2):

Write $n = 7 m$. If $m$ were odd, $7m$ would also be odd, contradiction. So $m$ is even, $m=2k$, and  $n = 14k$.